# ehcache 3 statistics spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache, mbeans

I read through the documentation for ehcache 3 and its a bit confusing in the context of spring cache.  My configuration is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache:config updateCheck="true"
 monitoring="autodetect"
 dynamicConfig="true"
  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
  xmlns:ehcache='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
  xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd 
  http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.1.xsd">
<ehcache:annotation-driven />
<ehcache:service> 
  <service>
    <jsr107:defaults enable-management="true" enable-statistics="true"/> 
  </service>
 </ehcache:service>

  <ehcache:cache alias="xyz" statistics="true">
    <ehcache:key-type>java.lang.Long</ehcache:key-type>
    <ehcache:value-type>a.b.c.something</ehcache:value-type>
    <ehcache:expiry>
     <ehcache:ttl unit="seconds">10</ehcache:ttl>
    </ehcache:expiry>
    <ehcache:resources>
      <ehcache:heap unit="entries">10000</ehcache:heap>
      <ehcache:offheap unit="MB">1</ehcache:offheap>
    </ehcache:resources>
    <jsr107:mbeans enable-statistics="true"/>
  </ehcache:cache>
  ...
  </ehcache:config>
```

```html
  cache:
    jcache:
      config: classpath*:ehcache.xml
```

My yaml:

```html
  cache:
    jcache:
      config: classpath*:ehcache.xml
```

A bit lost as to what I should be looking for - I thought org.ehcache can be profiled and would show up.  I dont see anything with that pattern in jvisualvm.  Or not sure how to read the information.  Used to be straightforward in ehcache 2.x  Any help would be appreciated.  I would like to get the size and count of the cache. Number of elements currently in the cache etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To be sure how to answer would need the spring configuration and some Java code. However, your current `ehcache.xml` seems a weird medley of Ehcache 2 and 3. And the `yaml` is wrong.

So, in order, you need a `pom.xml` including JSR-107

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The, the `application.yml` should have a `spring` prefix.

```
spring:
  cache:
    jcache:
      config: classpath:ehcache.xml
```

For the cache to be enabled, you need something like `@EnableCaching` or `<cache:annotation-driven/>` which should be in the Spring configuration, not in the `ehcache.xml`.

Finally, I've cleaned up everything that shouldn't be in the `ehcache.xml`. I'm also using a default namespace to make it more readable. Also, since Spring caches are untyped, you need to remove the `key-type` and `value-type` from the cache configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
                xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
                xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
                xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd
  http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.1.xsd">

  <service>
      <jsr107:defaults enable-management="true" enable-statistics="true"/>
  </service>

  <cache alias="xyz">
    <expiry>
      <ttl unit="seconds">10</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <resources>
      <heap unit="entries">10000</heap>
      <offheap unit="MB">1</offheap>
    </resources>
    <jsr107:mbeans enable-statistics="true"/>
  </cache>

</config>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The yml was a snippet.  Yes, I do include the spring prefix